# How to remove error message - using jquery.multiselect by eric hynds

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a page using jquery.multiselect, also using jquery.validation. Validation working great on all fields except the multiselect field.  The problem is if the user submits the form, it will throw the error, but if the user goes to correct the error by clicking a checkbox, the error remains.  Any thoughts on how to remove the error if a box is clicked?

Key links:

My form: http://ehslax50.com/register.asp

Multiselect: http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery this can be done by listening to the click event

```
//listen for click event on multi select years
$('input[name="multiselect_years"]').on('click', function()
{
  //hide error label when that event happens
  $('label[for="years"].error').hide()
});
```

Comment: Thank you!  Works great.